# How to protect REST API with CORS?

Tags: rest, cors

I am developing a web application where data will be accessible both to frontend and to various clients (`curl` & co.) through REST API. Both frontend and backend will be on the same domain. I would like to protect my frontend with CORS, which presents a dilemma for me. If I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` then all other clients will be able to access API, but my own frontend will be more exposed. On the other hand setting it to my domain forces clients to supply (fake) `Origin` headers and effectively disallows using browsers as clients (via frontend on different domains).

How is this usually solved? Should I use two different endpoint for API, one for public access and the other for use with my frontend? I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: Do your clients (your frontend and other client) have access to different functionality or do you return different data (example: more data to you website) when you call the same function?

Comment: No, the functionality is the same. Of course, each user is authenticated so the data is different per user (but each user can use either my frontend or their own client and they would get the same data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CORS is relevant only for browsers & HTML. `curl` doesn't care about it. So if you restrict your service to be accessed only from your domain, then other *sites* won't be able to access it.

To make your service available for them - those sites could set up nginx or apache to forward some of the traffic to your service. So 3d-party sites will access their own host with their own CORS configured and their host will communicate with your service.

Another (similar) solution would be for you to set up 2 host names (subdomains?) that lead to the same service. And expose one to your own site (with strict CORS) and the other - for external clients.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to protect my frontend with CORS

CORS doesn't protect anything in the frontend, CORS is a way to prevent cross-site scripting from web sites which are not authorized. The CORS headers are effective only for browser's XHR calls. It will not prevent direct loading of resources.

> If I set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * then all other clients will be able to access API, but my own frontend will be more exposed.

IMHO you frontend will be accessible as before. The CORS headers are effective only for browser's XHR calls

> On the other hand setting it to my domain forces clients to supply (fake) Origin headers and effectively disallows using browsers as clients (via frontend on different domains).

Not really. 
There are several options:

- You can have a list of allowed hosts for each API client (effective you set the origin header based on the client's authentication) This is what many of API providers do (FB, Google, Amazon, ..)
- the browser (in the XHR calls) sends the `Origin` header and you could check and sent or deny the hostname from the Origin header

And non-browsers clients are not restricted by the CORS headers.

> Should I use two different endpoint for API, one for public access and the other for use with my frontend? I would appreciate some advice

As written in the comments - assuming the functionality is the same and users are authenticated, then IMHO there is no point in having separate services for internal / public use.

These all are answers for particular questions, however I am still not convinced it is clear what/why/how you want to achieve.